# How to sort my buttons and entry using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to align labels with the Entry boxes. Please let me know how to align and debug in the following program of tkinter.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
    def create_widgets(self):
        # nazwa modułu
        self.MDF_name = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.MDF_name['text'] = "MDF"
        self.MDF_name.grid(row=1, column=0)
        # okno do wpisywania sze
        self.w_sze_MDF = tkinter.Entry()
        self.w_sze_MDF.grid(row=1, column=2)
        # nazwa modułu
        self.plyta_name = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.plyta_name['text'] = "Płyta Wiórowa"
        self.plyta_name.grid(row=0, column=0)
        # okno do wpisywania sze
        self.w_sze_MDF = tkinter.Entry()
        self.w_sze_MDF.grid(row=0, column=2)
root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either specify a common master widget for both your Labels and Entry widgets or leave the first position of the widget constructor blank in order for the geometry manager to operate as you desire. It is a positional argument that defaults to None. So while you need not explicitly write the keyword master it is done in the example below to hightlight the changes required in your code to make the lables and entries align as requested.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
    def create_widgets(self):
        # nazwa modułu
        self.MDF_name = tkinter.Label(master=self, relief='raised')
        self.MDF_name['text'] = "MDF"
        self.MDF_name.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='we')
        # okno do wpisywania sze
        self.w_sze_MDF = tkinter.Entry(master=self)
        self.w_sze_MDF.grid(row=0, column=1)
        # nazwa modułu
        self.plyta_name = tkinter.Label(master=self, relief='raised')
        self.plyta_name['text'] = "Płyta Wiórowa"
        self.plyta_name.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
        # okno do wpisywania sze
        self.w_sze_MDF = tkinter.Entry(master=self)
        self.w_sze_MDF.grid(row=1, column=1)
root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.place` for the aligning of labels, in my opinion it is the best out of `.pack`, `.grid` & `.place` for aligning widgets exactly where you want it to be. You can also read the manuals here https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/ & for [`.place`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm)